TensorFlow: "Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed" error in custom BatchNormalization layer
I'm encountering an error while using a custom BatchNormalization layer in TensorFlow for an object detection project. The error message I'm getting is:
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Exception encountered when calling BatchNormalization.call().
Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.

The error seems to be originating from the BatchNormalization class's call method. Here's the relevant part of my custom BatchNormalization layer:
import tensorflow as tf

class BatchNormalization(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
    """
    Make trainable=False freeze BN for real (the og version is sad)
    """

    def call(self, x, training=False):
        if training is None:
            training = False
        training = tf.logical_and(training, self.trainable)
        return super().call(x, training)

I've tried to modify the code to handle the None value for the training argument using tf.cond, like so:
training = tf.cond(tf.equal(training, None), lambda: tf.constant(False), lambda: training)

However, I'm still receiving the same error. Can anyone help me understand why I'm encountering this error and how to resolve it?

The issue is that when using tf.logical_and, you're converting your bool variable to a tf.Tensor (which has a boolean dtype). However, the call method of the  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization layer expects the keyword argument training to be a python bool and not a tf.Tensor. To fix it,  replace your call to tf.logical_and by using the python and keyword.
training = training and self.trainable

